# How to share a single Twilio number between multiple clients?

Tags: twilio

I'm creating a twilio service with three actors:

- The **customer**, a person who calls a company
- The **company**, a company who forwards calls to the service-provider
- The **service-provider** (that's us), an entity that services the customer on behalf of the company

Herein lies the catch: **The service provider needs to be able to identify the company associated with the customer** but it may only use a single phone number. We cannot use multiple phone numbers for cost reasons (the margins are **that** low). We cannot use the caller id because a single customer may be associated with multiple companies.

I am familiar with Twilio's [ForwardedFrom](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request) field but as mentioned [here](http://forum.twilio.com/twilio/topics/i_am_getting_inaccurate_forwardedfrom_data) it isn't always reliable. In fact, forwarding from my cell-phone carrier results in a null `ForwardedFrom` field.

**How can we (reliably) identify the company who redirected a customer to us without using multiple phone numbers?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be possible at this time (2013). I will keep an eye out for new answers and will accept them if this becomes possible at a later time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the number + extension. http://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/ivrs-extensions

Comment: The **customer** being forwarded doesn't know what extension the **company** is associated with. He expects the service provider to know which company is being serviced.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could build a sort of phone tree system, asking the caller the nature of their problem, which would be an indicator of the company their call is related to.

My guess is that you wouldn't want an outright "which company are is your call related to?" question, because that would feel cheap to the customer. So, maybe you could formulate a question or series of questions that wouldn't be overtly asking which company their calling about, but the answer(s) would clearly indicate on the service-provider end which company the call is about.

This could be further whittled down on the service-provider end by doing a company lookup based on the customer's calling number - if it matches a certain company (or set of companies), then that automatically limits the potential company they could be calling about.

Another possibility (if it fits in your use case) is some sort of we'll-call-you setup. Perhaps the customer could text/email requesting a call, and the information they'd provide in the text/email/online-form-submission would indicate the company they wish to speak about (again, you could use questions that aren't overtly "which company do you want a call from?").

Then again, if it's such a low-margin operation, maybe the companies are ok with a phone-tree style call-in number, where the customer needs to select a company they're calling about which is then indicated to the service-provider.

Comment: I appreciate the elaborate answer but I'm building a voice-mail system of sorts. As such, I'm not allowed to ask any questions before answering the call. A customer calls a company, the company forwards to me, and I need to record the customer's message right away.

Answer (score 0):

In general, I'd recommend separate numbers per customer but since you say that's not an option, here's another approach:

When the call comes into the Company, that individual leg gets a CallSid which is a unique identifier. When the call is forwarded to the Service Provider, that separate leg also gets a CallSid. Let's call them CallSidOne and CallSidTwo respectively.

If you then query based on CallSidTwo, you'll get back its instance properties as listed here:
http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call#instance-properties

The key property here is "parent_call_sid" which *should* be CallSidOne. Therefore, you can connect the two segments together.. then you can query on CallSidOne which gives you the ability to track who called which customer called which customer when.

Does that solve your problem?

~Twilio employee